# Azure AD B2C add parameter in reply url

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, callbackurl

Is there a way to add a specific value to a reply url (not included in the token) in order to manage a specific workflow.
Example, invitation process in which :

- we call in a sign-in or sign-up policy and we put in the url a parameter a custom key (related to the invitation)
- if sign-in or sign-up succeed, the reply url will also return the custom key

I don't know if it's possible or another possibility exists...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to add a specific value to a reply url (not included in
>   the token) in order to manage a specific workflow.

Please take a look at `state` parameter. You can use this parameter to send arbitrary data as part of your request and it gets returned back to you in response.

From the [`documentation link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code):

[image]

Comment: OK no potential risk for using this paramater in this way ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by potential risk?

Comment: I don't know, it's specified that it is generally used for putting the state or to prevent cross-site request attack... But the sentence "it can be string of any content that you want" is quite clear

Comment: @user1523812 - yes, it needs to be signed or encrypted.  See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47929148/185123)